# System.Security.VerificationException in Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, code-access-security

C# Winform application working fine. But after Obfuscation and Merging of required dlls getting
System.Security.VerificationException (Type argument 'T' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T').

Comment: Turn off _Obfuscation and Merging_ then.

Comment: What do you mean by Turn off Obfuscation and Merging ?